# How to import gmail contacts with mail address only without password in omnicontacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, google-contacts-api

I would like to import the gmail contacts by only with email address not pwd.
Is there any chance in google api something like facebook graph api to providing feeds
without user pwd and only with fb username.

Does this make sense?

Please help me who have idea about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using ruby on rails. You can check out the contacts gem

https://github.com/mislav/contacts

This allows you to fetch users’ contact lists from your web application without asking them to provide their passwords, but you have to register your app with google. The way you use it is similar to Facebook graph api.

Answer (score 0):

There is also pretty good gem for gmail and yahoo https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts